InputStreamReader.read never finishes reading and never returns
I have an InputStream and the following code works, reading some bytes from the input stream and creating a string with them:
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int i = in.read(buffer, 0, 1024); //"in" is the input stream
String line = new String(buffer, 0, i);
System.out.println(line);

but the following doesn't, wrapping the input stream in InputStreamReader and trying to read from it never returns and stucks waiting:
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
reader.read(); //this call never returns...

When I debug I can see that the underlying read() of the input stream gets called multiple times and returns bytes as expected, but the reader doesn't return.
Both of the above code blocks are inside an executor task, maybe it's related:
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
executor.submit(
  () -> {
  //Read from streams..
});

I have the same problem with BufferedReader, for it the readLine method never returns.
Why can reading the raw input stream work but using readers not?

If the first read byte belongs to a character that comprises of multiple bytes it will wait. What type of characters are contained in this stream? Plain ASCII or umlaut characters, or even unicode characters from different languages or emojis? => it all depends on the content you are reading.

it's a log file of an application so plain ASCII, but the stream reads many bytes from it (more than 1024) but still doesn't return any UTF-8 characters... the first byte read is 50 btw (when int is printed)

maybe something wrong with the encoding... since it is "plain ASCII", you can try StandardCharsets.US_ASCII (or ISO_8859_1) instead of UTF_8

Thanks alot but ASCII encoding didn't work either...

It may help if you show the code that accesses the InputStream and the bytes of the successful reads.
